# How to store Technical Specifications and features of Vehicles in a MySql Table

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-performance

I want to store the technical specifications of the Vehicles in a mysql table. Where table design should be optimized enough to manage various DB Operations (Such as Updating or Selecting datasets) using PHP.

There are more than 100 fields of vehicle features and specifications, for which I am very much confused which database architecture to be followed for best optimization.

For example, the fields are: **engineType, displacement, mileage, topSpeed, wheelSize, groundClearance, rearAcVents, frontAcVtents, cdPlayer** and so on...

Should I create individual column for each new specification or feature or store all the specs and json in a single column with json encoded data?

If i create columns, then there would be n number of columns logically. That would reach the maximum limit of mysql columns and may affect performance as well?

Comment: Primarily opinion based, who stores all data in a JSON format?? what if you want to search through the data? order or filter it?

Comment: You could take rearAcVents and frontAcVents and have one column AcVents and have it be an enumerated type to accommodate the different types of AcVents. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Create columns for the values that you will commonly be filtering or sorting on.  But the rest in a single JSON column.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 0):

In designing a database, 100 fields isn't necessarily "too many". I would first look at all of the data and consider if all features and specifications should be in 1 table.  I would not do that. Not only for performance considerations, but in looking at what types of queries would be run against the data.  Instead, consider:

Table: vehicle: year, make, model, size specs, a PK ID field

Table: electrical: electrical specs

Table: engine: engine, transmission & drive train specs

Table: Features: creature comfort specs (doors, radios, color options, etc.)

Any other large grouping you need. You could include the "features" in the basic vehicle table.

This way queries are not going row by row through a huge table, and you can more easily have one to many relationships like vehicle to transmission or vehicle to color. And you can slice and dice your data anyway you could think of.